# Accessing main queue via DispatchGroup vs. DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using DispatchGroup in a class that runs on a background thread. Occasionally, I need to update the UI, so I call the following code:

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  self.delegate?.moveTo(sender: self, location: location)
  self.delegate?.updateLabel(sender: self, item: self.currentItem)
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. However, if I call the same code, via `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`, like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.delegate?.moveTo(sender: self, location: location)
  self.delegate?.updateLabel(sender: self, item: self.currentItem)
}
```

...the delegate call gets made. I was under the impression `dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { }` is equivalent to `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`.

Why are these not the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your `dispatchGroup` empty (i.e. have no blocks running) at the time when you call `notify(queue:)`? If not, as [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016066-notify) states `dispatchGroup.notify(queue:)`

> Schedules a work item to be submitted to a queue when a group of previously submitted block objects have completed.

Which means that your closure will be executed only after the last `leave()` call, when the group becomes empty. And, of course, `enter()`s and `leave()`s must be balanced.

Consider the following example:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
someLongRunningTask() {
  // completion callback
  group.leave()
}

group.enter()
anotherLongRunningTask() {
  // completion callback
  group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
  print("all set")
}
```

In this example `all set` will be printed only after two callbacks with `group.leave()` execute.

On the other hand, `DispatchQueue.main.async()` immediately submits the block to the target queue but it will not necessarily start right after that – there could be running, for example, `async` block with the `.barrier` flag.

**Update**: Implementation of the example above using `DispatchQueue` (hopefully, it makes things clear):

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
someLongRunningTask() {
  // completion callback
  group.leave()
}

group.enter()
anotherLongRunningTask() {
  // completion callback
  group.leave()
}

group.wait() // waits synchronously for the submitted work to complete
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  print("all set")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation! That squared me away.